# Service Worker brings up 504 when trying to request Sentry

Tags: angular, service-worker, sentry

My Angular app is using Service Worker and Sentry. When hard reloading the app, Sentry can be requested and responds with a 200. When normally loading the app (without hard reload) in network console it says 504 Gateway Timeout (from service worker). As Sentry is a bug tracking tool, Service Worker should not do any stuff with these requests. I am wondering because the request sent is a POST request. How can I configure the Service Worker to not intercept this POST request?

[Screenshot Network Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlIXJ.png)